# Clarification on SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Can someone tell me what is missing in the second Pivot example. It returns NULL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b405/2

Comment: Well yeah. There is no Car, Truck or Bicycle in your vehicle_parameters table. Nothing is missing in your statement, your result of `NULL` is correct. Why? What did you expect?

Comment: That way of asking a question is useless to other SO users. You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Considering SQL Fiddle tends to be down quite a bit, without including the code here it makes your question incredibly hard to answer.

Comment: @hvd I expected "make, year, engine, frame" as result. I misunderstood the concept. I changed as sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b405/18 and it's fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the literal answer:

> There is no Car, Truck or Bicycle in your vehicle_parameters table. Nothing is missing in your statement, your result of NULL is correct.

Here are some other samples of PIVOT you may want to look up: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
I think they explain dealing with nulls well.

Comment: Yeah I agree, nonetheless I added resource with useful example.

Comment: Thanks, I expected "make, year, engine, frame" as result. I misunderstood the way PIVOT works. I changed as http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b405/18